# Put default values in PHP API or in javascript (Vue)

Tags: javascript, php, default

**I have data from an API that may look like this:**

```php
return [
  'item1' => [
    'name' => 'hello',
    'description' => 'world'
  ],
  'item2' => [
    'name' => 'foo',
    'description' => 'foo'
  ]
];
```

In Vue I populate with more data, like `equal` to cache if name and description contains the same value.

**Simplified it will look like this:**

```
item1:
  name: hello
  description: world
  equal: false
item2:
  name: foo
  description: foo
  equal: true
```

I don't need to check for equals initially, but Vue/Vuex requires to still set it to something as a default value. Else it will not be reactive.

### Question

Should I set `equal` to the default value on the server side (PHP), or on the client side (js/Vue)?

It may be debatable, but I feel that one, server or client should be better, but which one and why?

- Performance - My guess is that PHP require more server power and javascript require more browser memory/processor?
- So far it seems that it's easier to set the defaults with PHP.

It there a clear winner?

Comment: It's redundant information so shouldn't be part of network traffic, I guess? On the client, in other words.

Comment: you can use an .env file where you can put your constants or default values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Chris G said:

> It's redundant information so shouldn't be part of network traffic, I guess? On the client, in other words.